# Retrieving multiple rows only if data is complete

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I am trying to retrieve rows that are relevant from a text file, however i am unsure of how i can get it done.

Below is the sample line in the `.txt` file.

```
Name : Alice 
Age : 23
Email : Alice@email.com

Name : John
Age : 24

Name : Peter
Age: 25
Email :Peter@email.com
```

So as seen from above, i am only interested to take the data of Alice and Peter because John's information is not complete (Missing the email row).

So the output should just be :

```
Name : Alice 
Age : 23
Email : Alice@email.com

Name : Peter
Age: 25
Email :Peter@email.com
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself towards solving the problem. SO community can help you out if you are stuck with a problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just print the records that have 3 lines:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' 'NF==3' file
Name : Alice
Age : 23
Email : Alice@email.com

Name : Peter
Age: 25
Email :Peter@email.com
```

You can even automate it to figure out how many lines each record should have instead of hard-coding `3`:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' 'NR==FNR{m=(NF>m?NF:m);next} NF==m' file file
Name : Alice
Age : 23
Email : Alice@email.com

Name : Peter
Age: 25
Email :Peter@email.com
```

That last assumes there's at least one record in your file that IS complete.

Comment: Hmm. The second approach would only work when the first record in the file is correct.

Comment: No it wouldn't. If it was written as `awk ...'NR==1{m=NF} NF==m' file` THEN you'd be right, but it's not.

Comment: Oh, I see. You are passing the same file twice. Nice. Completely misread this.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Poz '^Name.*\n^Age.*\n^Email.*(\n^$)*' file
```

Output:

```
Name : Alice 
Age : 23
Email : Alice@email.com

Name : Peter
Age: 25
Email :Peter@email.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk '/Name :/&&/Age :/&&/Email :/' RS='' ORS='\n\n' file
```

Following `man awk`:

> If `RS` is set to the null string, then records
>          are separated by blank lines.

This makes awk operating based on *records* rather *lines*. `/Name :/&&/Age :/&&/Email :/` checks if this records contain all required fields. If that is true, awk will print the record.

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '/Name/{ n=$0 }n && /Age/{ a=$0; rn=NR }a && /Email/ && (NR-rn == 1){ print n RS a RS $0 RS }' file
```

The output:

```
Name : Alice 
Age : 23
Email : Alice@email.com

Name : Peter
Age: 25
Email :Peter@email.com
```

Answer (score 1):

very terse perl:

```
perl -00 -lne 'print if tr/\n/\n/ == 2' file.txt
```

Comment: Without an explanation, this isn't as education as it could be. Could you edit your answer and maybe elaborate a bit about how it works, and how it solves this particular problem? This would also enable others to use your answer as a way of solving similar (but different) problems.